# Translation and rotation of coordinates

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I'm working on an app that takes the first image and finds the two red circles.
After that the app takes the second image, compares it with the first one  and returns the offsets in X, Y and angle.
What I need to do is, based on those offsets, return the little squares to it's original positions.
How can I get the offsets of the little squares with the information that I have? Or is there a better solution? The second image could be rotated and translated.

[image]

Comment: What does this mean in programming terms: "return the little squares to it's original positions" ?

Comment: Basically I need to calculate the coordinates of the translated and rotated squares based on the angle and the distance that I got with the circles.

Comment: How did you get angle and distance from the (red?) circles? Angle and distance to what?

Comment: I calculate the angle of the big rectangle with the two circles, so I can know the angle of both images. With distance I mean the difference in positions between the circles of the second image and the circles of the first image.

Comment: What if you rotate the right image 180 degrees?

Comment: google 2D rotation equation and unrotate by `atan2(dy0,dx0)-atan2(dy1,dx1)` ... where `dx?,dy?` are the deltas between your 2 found points (slopes of diagonal line) then just translate to match original position after rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position of the two small red circles:

```
x1 = {x1[0], x1[1]}     and    x2 = {x2[0], x2[1]}
```

Measured displacements:
the new small circles should have coordinates

```
{x1[0] + dx1[0], x1[1] + dx1[1]}   and   {x2[0] + dx2[0], x2[1] + dx2[1]}
```

You are given as input the data:

```
  x1 = {x1[0], x1[1]}     and    x2 = {x2[0], x2[1]}
 dx1 = {dx1[0], dx1[1]}   and   dx2 = {dx2[0], dx2[1]}
```

This is enough to calculate how the rest of the points and squares have moved, including the angle of rotation.

```
v[0] = x2[0] - x1[0];
v[1] = x2[1] - x1[1];
w[0] = v[0] + dx2[0] - dx1[0];
w[1] = v[1] + dx2[1] - dx1[1];
norm_v = math.Sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1]);
norm_w = math.Sqrt(w[0] * w[0] + w[1] * w[1]);
```

If everything is correct, `norm_v = norm_w` (up to numerical error). Maybe check it.

```
cos_angle = ( v[0] * w[0] + v[1] * w[1] ) / (norm_v * norm_w);
sin_angle = (- v[1] * w[0] + v[0] * w[1]) / (norm_v * norm_w);
```

So any other point changes by the transformation law:

```
x_new[0] = cos_angle * (x_old[0] - x1[0]) - sin_angle * (x_old[1] - x1[1]) + x1[0];
x_new[0] = sin_angle * (x_old[0] - x1[0]) + cos_angle * (x_old[1] - x1[1]) + x1[1];
```

Comment: It's okay that w[0] and w[1] are the same?

Comment: @EmmanuelLG A copy and paste error. I corrected it.

Comment: @EmmanuelLG I made some corrections to account to whether the rotation is clockwise or counter-clockwise.